# Selecting all but one field?

Tags: sql, mysql

instead of `SELECT * FROM mytable`, i would like to select all fields EXCEPT one (namely, the 'serialized' field, which stores a serialized object). this is because i think that losing that field will speed up my query by a lot. however, i have so many fields and am quite the lazy guy. is there a way to say...

```
`SELECT ALL_ROWS_EXCEPT(serialized) FROM mytable`
```

?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no convention in SQL to get all but one (or a number of designated) column(s).

Being explicit about what column(s) are being returned, preferably using a table alias (even if only for one table), is ideal.